# instants and sorceries with activated abilities while on the stack

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I only know of one instant with an activated ability: [lightning storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5blightning%20storm%5d). Are there any other instants or sorceries that have an activated abilities while on the stack? Also are there any permanents that have an activated ability that only works on the stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lightning Storm appears to be the only spell with an activated ability that functions on the stack.

There are a couple of other spells that have an unusual *static* ability that functions on the stack: [Torrent of Lava](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTorrent%20of%20Lava%5d) and [Kaervek's Torch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKaervek%27s%5d%2b%5bTorch%5d). (There's also the more common ["(this spell) can't be countered"](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22can%27t+be+countered%22) static ability or the ["when you cast (this spell)"](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22when+you+cast+~%22) triggered ability found especially on Eldrazi cards.)

We can check this by [by searching for all instants and sorceries with an `:` in their text](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28t%3Ainstant+or+t%3Asorcery%29+o%3A%22%3A%22+-o%3Aeldrazi) (and we'll filter out mention of Eldrazi scion/spawn tokens for convenience) — the only one in there with an activated ability that functions on the stack is Lightning Storm.

We can also make a regex search for [cards that mention the word "stack" at all](https://scryfall.com/search?q=re%3A%22%5Cbstack%5Cb%22). For abilities to function on the stack, they'll have to mention being able to function that zone. From that search we also see Torrent of Lava and Kaervek's Touch.

Comment: Thank you for posting that link where you search using regex. I had no idea any magic website supported regex so that will make these searches a lot easier in the future!

Comment: @MaxYoung [Gatherer itself supports using Regex](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Help.aspx#regex) though knowledge of that is pretty obscure. It doesn't always behave... [I'm not sure how I'd do the same search on Gatherer since it doesn't seem to work.](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[\bstack\b])

Comment: You have made my day by showing me this. If I could up vote this answer again I would.

Comment: @MaxYoung Glad to help. \o/

Comment: There are other abilities that function on the stack that don't explicitly say so. "~ can't be countered", for example, is a static ability that only functions on the stack.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks, I've updated with that & another.